# Simplifying Cosh[a] + Sin[a] + Sinh[a]

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Why does `FullSimplify[Cosh[a] + Sinh[a] + Sin[a]]` not return `Exp[a]+Sin[a]`
?

Is this some bug in Mathematica or am I being stupid? Is the latter not simpler by some measure?

I've ran into this several times so I guess others have too, therefore i find it hard to believe it is a bug (it should have been reported many times and surely have shown up during their testing).

Comment: use `TrigToExp`.

Comment: @Kuba But `FullSimplify[TrigToExp[Cosh[a] + Sinh[a] + Sin[a]]]` takes us back where we started.

Comment: @MichaelE2 then don't do that. :) btw, I could bet it worked without ComplexExpand but now I tried and it seems necessary: `ComplexExpand@TrigToExp[Cosh[a] + Sin[a] + Sinh[a]]`.

Comment: @Kuba Cool (of course `ComplexExpand` treats `a` as if it were `Real`, which might give invalid results in similar cases).  I was busy figuring out why `FullSimplify` fails.  I think it's interesting and that this question should not be closed.

Comment: @Kuba, I'm not asking how to simplify the expression but why the above way of simplifying does not work. I can always find ways of simplifying by trial and error though if I understood why the above didn't work I could use a more direct approach.

Comment: @Petter understood.

Comment: A similar example，`FullSimplify[3 Cos[t] + Cos[3 t] + 4 Sin[t]^3]` couldn't get `4 (Cos[t]^3 + Sin[t]^3)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One problem seems to be that the only pair of terms in a `Plus[t1, t2,...,]` expression that are simplified are the last two.  This shows up not only in the starting expression `Cosh[a] + Sin[a] + Sinh[a]` (in that order due to the `Orderless` attribute of `Plus`) but also in `TrigToExp`:

```
TrigToExp[Cosh[a] + Sinh[a] + Sin[a]]
(*  1/2 I E^(-I a) - 1/2 I E^(I a) + E^a  *)
```

When this is simplified we get the original expression back.

Probably it was thought that pointlessly simplifying $n(n-1)/2$ pairs of terms in a long expression would probably slow down simplification too much.  Since one pair but not all pairs are checked, I feel this was a deliberate choice.  I'd be reluctant to call it a bug, but it certainly is a shortcoming in this case.

A workaround is to create a transformation function that checks all pairs:

```
ClearAll[allpairs];
allpairs[e_Plus] := 
  First@SortBy[e - # + FullSimplify[#] & /@ Subsets[e, {2}], Simplify`SimplifyCount];
allpairs[e_] := e;

FullSimplify[Cosh[a] + Sinh[a] + Sin[a], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, allpairs}]
(*  E^a + Sin[a]  *)
```

Another workaround, showing that some standard identities are missing from the automatic transformations:

```
FullSimplify[Cosh[a] + Sinh[a] + Sin[a], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic,
     # /. Cosh[z_] -> Exp[z] - Sinh[z] &,
     # /. Sinh[z_] -> Exp[z] - Cosh[z] &}]

(*  E^a + Sin[a]  *)
```

Comment: The documentation states that FullSimplify "tries a wide range of transformations on expr involving elementary and special functions and returns the simplest form it finds. ", sure a wide range is somewhat subjective but surely simplifying Cosh[a] + Sinh[a] is included in a wide range so I would call this a bug.

Comment: @Petter `FullSimplify` does simplify `Cosh[a] + Sinh[a]`.

Comment: not always as i pointed out above?

Comment: @Petter The point is that it only simplifies the last two terms in a sum, so it never tries to apply a transformation to `Cosh[a] + Sinh[a]` in your example.  Another way to look at it, perhaps more to your liking, is that it does not apply transformations like `Cosh[a] ->  Exp[a] - Sinh[a]`.  From that viewpoint, one could argue that the range of transformations is not wide enough.  You should report it to WRI, since you think it is a bug.

Comment: I understand your explanation and thank you for figuring it out. I think that is how it works too after some testing. Though to me that is clearly a bug. I don't think quadratic complexity is too bad when simplifying an expression and especially not if it is this small. Technically this is subjective but in practice it makes no sense that fullsimplify can use identities of hypergeometric functions when this simple test case fails. By wri do you mean wolfram? I've reported several bugs to them, they have confirmed and told me it will be fixed. Several versions later they are still there...

Comment: @Petter Yes, WRI is Wolfram Research Inc (but they may have dropped the Inc). I've reported several bugs, too. Many have been fixed, and some not. It's not always clear why they are not (the fix caused other problems, disagreement on how to fix it, low priority, etc.).

Comment: @Petter "I don't think quadratic complexity is too bad when simplifying an expression and especially not if it is this small". This is worth further discussion. I'm inclined to agree with it. Perhaps though, it would lead to great confusion to users at the boundary of "small".

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** As commented on by Kuba

```
expr = Cosh[a] + Sinh[a] + Sin[a];
```

Initially assume that `a` is real (default for [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html))

```
expr2 = expr // TrigToExp // ComplexExpand

(* E^a + Sin[a] *)
```

Then check if the expressions are equal for all (complex) values of `a`

```
expr == expr2 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

**EDIT 2:** Alternatively, since Michael E2 states that Mathematica "simplifies the last two terms in a sum", vary the ordering of the terms

```
SortBy[Total /@ FullSimplify@Table[TakeDrop[expr, {n}], {n, 3}], 
  LeafCount][[1]]

(* E^a + Sin[a] *)
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** There is a simple *specific to the case solution* as well:

```
FullSimplify[Cosh[a]+Sinh[a]+Sin[a],ExcludedForms->_Sin]
(* E^a+Sin[a] *)
```

The reason why it works is explained below.

---

Firstly, the simple solution: You need to use `ComplexExpand` as a transformation function:

```
FullSimplify[Cosh[a]+Sinh[a]+Sin[a],TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,ComplexExpand}]
(* E^a+Sin[a] *)
```

### Explanation

I do not know why this happens but my guess is as follows. The observation of OP is probably because of the way *transformation functions* work. If I have a transformation function **g**, then `FullSimplify` applies it to all subexpressions **f[x1,x2,...,xn]** and checks **g[f[x1...xn]]** is simpler than **f[x1...xn]** (well, not one by one for each subexpression but the whole expression). In particular, this means that `FullSimplify` compares

```
Cosh[a] + Sin[a] + Sinh[a]
```

and

```
1/2 I E^(-I a) - 1/2 I E^(I a) + E^a
```

where second output follows from the transformation function `TrigToExp`. Here, the key point is this: Since `Plus` has the `Flat` attribute, `TrigToExp` also applies to `Sin[a]`, and one cannot avoid that. Say, if `Plus` did not have this attribute, we could have had a scenario where the transformation is applied only the other two without affecting `Sin[a]`, which is possible only if they are not at the same subexpression.

This explanation is in contrast to @Michael's explanation as far as I understand. In particular, one can see that this simplification is no issue if the middle term was not expanded by `TrigToExp`:

```
FullSimplify[Cosh[a]+Sinc[a]+Sinh[a]]
(* E^a+Sinc[a] *)
```

in contrast to, say,

```
FullSimplify[Cosh[a]+Cos[a]+Sinh[a]]
(* Cos[a]+Cosh[a]+Sinh[a] *)
```

One can check that indeed `TrigToExp` expands `Cos` but not `Sinc`. So the issue is not the order of terms nor that Fullsimplify does not consider different pairs.

Once we add `ComplexExpand` into the transformation functions, we now have `FullSimplify` comparing original expression with `ComplexExpand[TrigToExp[#]]&` transformation, and these are:

```
{#,ComplexExpand[TrigToExp[#]]}&[Cosh[a]+Cos[a]+Sinh[a]]
(* {Cos[a]+Cosh[a]+Sinh[a],E^a+Cos[a]} *)
```

Now since one expression is shorter than the other, `FullSimplify` can immediately choose the correct one!

### Summary

I would say that there is no bug with `FullSimplify`, at most a shortcoming. The *solution* I proposed above is actually inherently using another information we presented, that $a$ is real (even though the result is actually true for a bigger domain). That `FullSimplify` can do better simplifications under restricted domains even though the simplifications are actually correct for the original domain is disturbing, but it is not a bug, only a shortcoming.

Comment: It seems trig functions are treated specially.  So when a trig function separates  `Cosh[a]` and `Sinh[a]`, then the transformation does not occur in the plain `FullSimplify`.  It's as if the trig functions are culled and simplified en masse. (I can't see inside the transformation, only what sub-expressions are treated.)

Comment: I updated my answer with an IMO-better solution, which avoids this issue without domain restriction.